# nodejs / javascript Combine Same Items and set highest/lowest price

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this Array, and i want to stack them, that i only have each item one time, but i need the highest and lowest price in it.

Thats the array i have

```
[ { sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Factory New)',
price: 2003892,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Minimal Wear)',
price: 1703308,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Field-Tested)',
price: 1345613,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Well-Worn)',
price: 1170684,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Battle-Scarred)',
price: 1112150,
caseid: '7' }]
```

There you can see that the lowest "price" is 1112150 and the highest of that item is 2003892

Thats what i want:

```
 [ { sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Factory New)',
highestprice: 2003892,
lowestprice: 1112150,
caseid: '7' }]
```

I want to have the highest "price" of every sku and the lowest "price".
Combined in one Array result like that last i posted.

Comment: What do you mean by "stack"? Do you want to sort an array and remove duplicates?

Comment: Your result makes no sense. `name` matches the one with the highest price, but not the lowest.

Comment: I mean you see what i mean. I have that array on top, and that what i want. I dont know how to descripte that. I Only want to combine all same sku but want to safe the highest in "price" and the lowest "price" of the same skus. I updated a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and look for the same object with the same `sku`. Then take min and max values.

```js
var array = [ { sku: '199', name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Factory New)', price: 2003892, caseid: '7' }, { sku: '199', name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Minimal Wear)', price: 1703308, caseid: '7' }, { sku: '199', name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Field-Tested)', price: 1345613, caseid: '7' }, { sku: '199', name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Well-Worn)', price: 1170684, caseid: '7' }, { sku: '199', name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Battle-Scarred)', price: 1112150, caseid: '7' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { sku, name, price, caseid }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => sku === o.sku);
        if (!temp) {
            return r.concat({ sku, name, highestprice: price, lowestprice: price, caseid });
        }
        temp.lowestprice = Math.min(price, temp.lowestprice);
        temp.highestprice = Math.max(price, temp.highestprice);
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what i want :) Danke ;)

Comment: How did you reach to the point what `name` is to be shown in result as all names are different in the OP and also it was not mentioned what logic to use to show name apart from the output (that too not mentioned explicitly)? Did you infer anything we missed

Answer (score 0):

This function should give you the output you require:

```
function findHiLo(arr, sku) {
  let min = +Infinity;
  let max = -Infinity;
  let max_index = 0;

  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]["sku"] === sku) {
      if(arr[i]["price"] < min) min = arr[i]["price"];
      if(arr[i]["price"] > max) {
        max = arr[i]["price"];
        max_index = i;
      }
    }
  }

  return { "sku": sku,
           "name": arr[max_index]["name"],
           "highestprice": max,
           "lowestprice": min,
           "caseid": "7" };
}
```

It goes through the entire array, and looks for items with the given "sku". In the process, it finds the one with the highest and lowest price.

When run on your data like this: `findHiLo(data, '199')` it returns the following object:

```
{ sku: "199", name: "FAMAS | God of War (Factory New)", highestprice: 2003892, lowestprice: 1112150, caseid: "7" }
```

The name is copied from the item with the highest price.

The only thing I'm unsure of is "caseid" property. I set it to "7" in this function, you may want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript arrays (as well as in Java) there is a method called sort.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

Here's how to implement it into your example:

```js
let array = [ { sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Factory New)',
price: 2003892,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Minimal Wear)',
price: 1703308,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Field-Tested)',
price: 1345613,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | God of War (Well-Worn)',
price: 1170684,
caseid: '7' },
{ sku: '199',
name: 'FAMAS | The expensive God of War (Battle-Scarred)',
price: 111215000,
caseid: '7' }];

let sorted = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return Math.sign(b.price - a.price);
  /* 
   * This compares the prices. Sign returns 1, if
   * the value is positive, -1 when negative and zero
   * when 0 is given.
   */
});

// OUTPUT
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
  JSON.stringify(sorted)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean by stack, but from what I understand from your question, you could try this

```
    let highestPrice = 0;
    let lowestPrice = 0;
    let sku = ' ';
    let caseID = ' ';
    let name = ' ';

    let newObj = {};

    // Let's call your array *arr*, you could do this

    arr.map((elem, index) => {
     if (elem.price > highestPrice ) {
       highestPrice = elem.price;
       sku = elem.sku;
       caseID = elem.caseid;
       name = elem.name;
     }
    if (elem.price < lowestPrice ) {
       lowestPrice = elem.price;
     }
   });

   newObj = {
     sku: sku, 
     highestprice: highestPrice, 
     lowestprice: lowestPrice,
     caseid: caseID;
     name: name
   }
```

Comment: why are using map ? map returns a new array. you should use `forEach` instead

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm just used to it. Thanks a lot, I think I'd start using forEach now

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm just used to it. Thanks a lot, I think I'd start using forEach now